# DefaultTaskContainer#NamedDomainObjectProvider.configure(Action) on task set cannot be executed in the current context

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting this error when I try to connect my app with firebase.[image]

[image]
and here are Gradle scripts
[image]

[image]

Comment: I literally just create new project and try to connect my app with firebase.It connect easily but when try to add dependencies it just occurs and I don't know what to do

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google broke something in com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9

Change it to com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8 and I suspect it will work.  I have the same issue, and no amount of fiddling around with gradle scripts has fixed it, only downgrading.

Comment: It's also possible a future update to Firebase may fix things, so we can use com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9  However, currently the latest Firebase doesn't work, so com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8 is the last working version until one of these is updated.

Answer (score 2):

A new version 4.3.10 was released with a fix. Give it a try

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#google-services_plugin_v4-3-10

Comment: This also fixes the issue for me.  It's just 4.3.9 that has the issue in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'** in **build.gradle(project: app_name)**

It will be fixed.